# TreeView, HierarchicalDataTemplate and recursive Data

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

For my treeview I have two different classes that provide the ItemsSource.

```
public class TreeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class NodeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want my TreeView to display the Items in TreeViewModel and show hierarchical data as provided by the NodeViewModel.

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewMasterDetails.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewMasterDetails" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Height="Auto" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Margin="10" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Width="Auto">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:TreeViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:NodeViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Have tried to provide `Items` as the `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView`.
It does not show the data hierarchically, if displaying anything.

And I tried using the `ItemTemplate` instead of the `TreeView.Resources`, too.

What is wrong about it?

Perhaps a problem is the first `TextBlock Text Binding`? 
I want to display the `Name` property of the `NodeViewModel` in `Items` there.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate - binding to object with multiple child collections][1]. 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-multiple-child-co

Comment: Yes, I already have seen that. But it does not work here.

Comment: TreeViewModel does not have a Name property but that's probably not the issue

Comment: Any luck for doing this on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @sa_ddam213 said, you only need the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for `NodeViewModel`, but the only problem with your code was the missing braces (`{` and `}`) for `DataType="x:Type local:TreeViewModel"` in your data template definitions (it should be `DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}"`). Adding brackets and `ItemsSource` binding solves the problem:

The additional `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for `TreeViewModel` is not used, but it does not harm.

Comment: You are right, this is really the problem. Strangely enough, it works without the braces when used in `ItemTemplate`, but not in `Resources`.

Comment: @MareInfinitus It is because when used int `ItemTemplate`, it deos not need to look at the `DataType` property. You are directly saying to the `TreeView` to use the given template for items. So no need for `DataType`.

Answer (score 34):

You should only have to declare the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for `NodeViewModel` as this is the only thing showing in the `TreeView`, and bind the actual `ItemSource` to the `TreeView`

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Full Example

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication13"
        Title="MainWindow" x:Name="UI" Width="343" Height="744.625" >

    <TreeView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=TreeModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TreeViewModel TreeModel
    {
        get
        {
            return new TreeViewModel
            {
                Items = new ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>{
                           new NodeViewModel { Name = "Root", Children =  new ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> {
                              new NodeViewModel { Name = "Level1" ,  Children = new ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>{ 
                                  new NodeViewModel{ Name = "Level2"}}} } }}
            };
        }
    }
}

public class TreeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class NodeViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. Was sure that I have tried that before. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, I used your solution, however it doesn't seem to let me select anyhting and also the arrows on the left are missing. The tree looks frozen. One change I did to you code, I bind my TreeModel from my ViewModel class not from MainWindow.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251260/ if you want CheckBoxes that propagate instead of TextBlocks.