# Arrow is missing from the treeview/treeviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having a strange situation I have used two TreeViews in two different WPF applications. In both the same block of code/tag been used:

```
<TreeView Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="treeView1">
      <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubFolder, Source={StaticResource RootFolderDataProvider}}" Header="root" />
</TreeView>
```

In one of them the "root" shown next to its arrow, however, in the other one, only "root" is displayed and no arrow icon.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no arrow is displayed then that node doesn't have any children. If you feel that children exists and it is not displayed, then there is some problem in your TreeView Biding

Refer the following link for more details about treeView

[TreeView, HierarchicalDataTemplate and recursive Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240326/treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-recursive-data)

Comment: yes when I trace/debug the code it shows the data being assigned to children nodes. I'll look at it