# Recursive Treeview with multiple classes

Tags: c#, wpf, recursion, treeview

### the setup

I have a ViewModel with an `ObservableCollection<StructureItem>` and a View to display it.
The class itself is recursive:

```
public class StructureItem
{
        public List<StructureItem> Children { get; set; } = new List<StructureItem>();

        public List<IoItem> Ios { get; set; } = new List<IoItem>();

        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the `IoItem`

```
public class IoItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

The current xaml for the `TreeView`

```
<TreeView ItemsSource = "{Binding Structure}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="kernel:IoItem">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="kernel:StructureItem">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

### the problem

I have tried multiple different xaml, but the best result I get is that the `StructureItem` are displayed correctly (see above). The `IoItem` is either ignored or it breaks the whole Treeview.

**How to display this structure using xaml?**

Comment: Check this it seems similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240326/treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-recursive-data

Comment: What do you expect to see as node?

Comment: @I.Step I tried adapting this answer, but I end up with it failing at the highest level showing me only one TreeviewItem with the typename  of the StructureItem

Comment: @Rekshino for now only the name of each child and Io. As soon as that works I want to change formatting to highlight the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to to see the names of `IoItem`, then just add them to the `ItemTemplate` as e.g. `ListBox`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource = "{Binding Structure}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type kernel:IoItem}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="kernel:StructureItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Ios}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Putting multiple items into the template via a StackPanel (O_o) That was the solution, thanks.