# TreeView with CheckBoxes WPF

Tags: wpf, checkbox, treeview

I tried this sample [How to develop treeview with checkboxes in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251260/how-to-develop-treeview-with-checkboxes-in-wpf/52388124#52388124) to create a TreeView with checkbox but in this example you cannot have a family in another family.
So my question is how to create a full treeview with check box not only limited in one level?

So this is what I did

IParent.cs

```
interface IParent<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetChildren();
}
```

DataModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

public class Family : DependencyObject, IParent<object>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Members { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<object> IParent<object>.GetChildren()
    {
        return Members;
    }
}

public class Person : DependencyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ItemHelper.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

public class ItemHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChecked", typeof(bool?), typeof(ItemHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IParent<object> sect = d as IParent<object>;
        DependencyObject depObj = d as DependencyObject;

        if (sect != null)
        {
            if (((bool?)e.NewValue).HasValue)
            {
                foreach (DependencyObject p in sect.GetChildren())
                {
                    SetIsChecked(p, (bool?)e.NewValue);
                }
            }
        }

        if (depObj != null)
        {
            var parentObject = depObj.GetValue(ParentProperty) as IParent<object>;
            var parentDO = depObj.GetValue(ParentProperty) as DependencyObject;
            int ch = parentObject?.GetChildren()?.Where(
                x => GetIsChecked(x as DependencyObject) == true).Count() ?? 0;
            int un = parentObject?.GetChildren()?.Where(
                x => GetIsChecked(x as DependencyObject) == false).Count() ?? 0;
            if (un > 0 && ch > 0)
            {
                SetIsChecked(parentDO, null);
                return;
            }
            if (ch > 0)
            {
                SetIsChecked(parentDO, true);
                return;
            }
            SetIsChecked(parentDO, false);
        }
    }
    public static void SetIsChecked(DependencyObject element, bool? IsChecked)
    {
        element?.SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, IsChecked);
    }
    public static bool? GetIsChecked(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool?)element?.GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Parent", typeof(object), typeof(ItemHelper));

    public static void SetParent(DependencyObject element, object Parent)
    {
        element?.SetValue(ParentProperty, Parent);
    }
    public static object GetParent(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return element?.GetValue(ParentProperty);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication102.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication102"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="220" Width="250">

    <StackPanel>

        <TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Families}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Family}" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" >
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=(local:ItemHelper.IsChecked), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                        <CheckBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ItemHelper.IsChecked)}" Value="False" >
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </CheckBox.Style>
                    </CheckBox>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}" >
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=(local:ItemHelper.IsChecked), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                        <CheckBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(local:ItemHelper.IsChecked)}" Value="False" >
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </CheckBox.Style>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>

        <Button Content="?" Click="Button_PrintCrew_Click" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBoxCrew"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication102
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Family> Families { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Families = new ObservableCollection<Family>();
            this.Families.Add(new Family() { Name = "Simpsons", Members = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "Homer" }, new Person() { Name = "Bart" } } });
            this.Families.Add(new Family() { Name = "Griffin", Members = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "Peter" }, new Person() { Name = "Stewie" } } });
            this.Families.Add(new Family() { Name = "Fry", Members = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "Philip J." } } });

            foreach (Family family in this.Families)
                foreach (Person person in family.Members)
                    person.SetValue(ItemHelper.ParentProperty, family);
        }

        private void Button_PrintCrew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string crew = "";
            foreach (Family family in this.Families)
                foreach (Person person in family.Members)
                    if (ItemHelper.GetIsChecked(person) == true)
                        crew += person.Name + ", ";
            crew = crew.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
            this.textBoxCrew.Text = "Your crew: " + crew;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many other aspects of WPF development, this becomes much easier if you follow the `MVVM` pattern.

Create a common `ViewModel` base class to represent each node of the tree, with a collection of the same type to represent the node's children. This is where you would include the logic to handle ticking / unticking the parent / child items as appropriate. The `TreeView's` `ItemSource` is then bound to a simple collection of items to form the root level. The U.I. layout of the View is defined by a `HierachicalDataTemplate` for each distinct node type.

I covered this in a recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/), with sample code [here](https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView).

Comment: In fact I am not experienced enough in development to be able to understand your example but I thank you.