# Changes made to ObservableCollection item through a view do not change Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have recursive ObservableCollection representing directories and files.
My idea - if user Checked file, parent directories should know about this.

ViewModel:
class that contains Root Collection

```
 public class DirectoryTreeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        readonly ObservableCollection<DirectoryViewModel> _rootDirectories;

        public ObservableCollection<DirectoryViewModel> RootDirectory
        {
            get { return _rootDirectories; }
        }
```

classes representing Directories and Files

```
  public class DirectoryViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        readonly ObservableCollection<DirectoryViewModel> _childNode;
        readonly ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> _childFile;
        readonly DirectoryViewModel _parentNode;
        readonly Directory _directory;

        public DirectoryViewModel(Directory directory)
            :this(directory, null)
        {
            
        }

   

        private DirectoryViewModel(Directory directory, DirectoryViewModel parentNode)
        {
            _directory = directory;
            _parentNode = parentNode;
            _childNode = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryViewModel>();
            _childFile = new ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>();
            foreach (Directory dir in directory.directories )
            {
                _childNode.Add(new DirectoryViewModel(dir, this));
            }

            foreach (File file in directory.files)
            {
                _childFile.Add(new FileViewModel(file, this));
            }

        }
     

        public ObservableCollection<DirectoryViewModel> ChildNodes
        {
            get { return _childNode; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<FileViewModel> ChildFiles
        {
            get { return _childFile; }
        }
       
        public ObservableCollection<object> Nodes
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<object> childNodes = new ObservableCollection<object>();
                foreach (var dir in this.ChildNodes)
                    childNodes.Add(dir);
                foreach (var file in this.ChildFiles)
                    childNodes.Add(file);
                return childNodes;
            }
        }

        public Directory Directory
        {
            get => _directory;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _directory.Name; }
        }
        public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return _imageSource; }
        }

        public string Path
        {
            get { return _directory.Path; }
        }

        public bool Checked
        {
            get => _directory.Checked;
            set => _directory.Checked = value;
        }
       public bool hasCheckedFile
        {
            get => Directory.HasCheckedFile;
            set => Directory.HasCheckedFile = value;
        }
        
        public bool HasCheckedFile
        {
            get { return hasCheckedFile; }
            set
            {

                hasCheckedFile = value;
                if (_parentNode != null)
                    _parentNode.hasCheckedFile = hasCheckedFile;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasCheckedFile));
            }
        }

        

    }


    public class FileViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        readonly DirectoryViewModel _parentNode;
        readonly File _file;

        public FileViewModel(File file, DirectoryViewModel parentNode)
        {
            _parentNode = parentNode;
            _file = file;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _file.Name; }
        }

        
        public string ImageSource
        {
            get { return _imageSource; }
        }
        
        public string FullPath
        {
            get { return _file.FullPath; }
        }

        public bool Checked
        {
            get => _file.Checked;
            set => _file.Checked=value;
        }


        public bool IsCheckedToCopy
        {
            get { return Checked; }
            set
            {
                if (value == true)
                {
                    _parentNode.HasCheckedFile = true;
                    Checked = true;
                }

                else if (value == false)
                {
                    Checked = false;
                }

                _file.Checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCheckedToCopy));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
 <TreeView x:Name="treeView1" MaxHeight="700" Margin="4,117,-2,-28" ItemsSource="{Binding RootDirectory}" FontSize="12" >
                    <TreeView.DataContext>
                        <VM:DirectoryTreeViewModel/>
                    </TreeView.DataContext>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="CopyChBox"  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedToCopy, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                               
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Margin="1" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>


                                </Grid>
                            </CheckBox>

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
```

If i try to change collection item properties, my root collection "_rootdirectories" (ItemSource for TreeView) does not change.
How to implement listener so root collection knows about changes in collection items?

While Binding works well and all data from RooDirectory displayed,
If i try to change collection item properties, my root collection "_rootdirectories" (ItemSource for TreeView) does not change.
ObservableCollection knows about adding and deleting items, but i don't know how to implement listener so root collection will knew about changes in items properties made from View? Is it possible?
Or is it better to use BindingList instead ObservableCollection?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284805/17350254) refer to BindingList vs ObservableCollection and with the TreeView you would like to achieve something like this I believe [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613398/17350254)

Comment: How is the collection supposed to change when you set a property of an individual item? Or what do you mean? What exactly is your issue?